# Golang: Panic (Fatal Error) from C Code, Unable to Recover

Tags: c, go

I'm importing Leptonica C library into my Go app and using this for rotating and cropping an image.

For some reason it randomly produces a panic. I do mean random because I'm just testing at this point and so I'm processing exactly the same 20 images with exactly the same rotate/crop instructions repeatedly during my testing. Usually it works but around 1/50 times it will panic on a random one of the image, albeit usually one that has less on it (a mostly white image).

The panic given is:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x2 addr=0x7fed87890340 pc=0x7fed91e2de3e]

runtime stack:
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.sigpanic called from 0x7fed91e2de3e
runtime.throw(0x88bcc5)
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:520 +0x69
runtime: unexpected return pc for runtime.sigpanic called from 0x7fed91e2de3e
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/os_linux.c:222 +0x3d

goroutine 16 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0x401550, 0xc213ca98e8)
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/cgocall.c:143 +0xe5 fp=0xc213ca98d0 sp=0xc213ca9888
private/leptonica._Cfunc_pixClipRectangle(0x7fed8788ff00, 0x7fed8788ffd0, 0x0, 0x8c2a28)
        private/leptonica/_obj/_cgo_defun.c:80 +0x31 fp=0xc213ca98e8 sp=0xc213ca98d0
private/leptonica.(*goPix).Crop(0xc20af90000, 0x900, 0x90, 0x4d8, 0x9a8, 0x4202c1, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/go/src/private/leptonica/leptonica.go:154 +0xd8 fp=0xc213ca9960 sp=0xc213ca98e8
main.(*pageStruct).transformOriginal(0xc20805ae10, 0xc224772000, 0x69, 0x1)
        /home/root/go/frankenstein.go:1353 +0x30d fp=0xc213ca99c8 sp=0xc213ca9960
main.(*pageStruct).transformOriginalWithRecover(0xc20805ae10, 0xc224772000, 0x69, 0x1, 0x0, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/root/go/frankenstein.go:1403 +0xe1 fp=0xc213ca9a38 sp=0xc213ca99c8
main.(*book).processPages(0xc208a90000, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/root/go/frankenstein.go:1542 +0x305 fp=0xc213ca9e48 sp=0xc213ca9a38
main.main()
        /home/root/go/frankenstein.go:1970 +0x3f5 fp=0xc213ca9f50 sp=0xc213ca9e48
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:247 +0x11a fp=0xc213ca9fa8 sp=0xc213ca9f50
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445 fp=0xc213ca9fb0 sp=0xc213ca9fa8
created by _rt0_go
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:97 +0x120

goroutine 19 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.park(0x424c70, 0x8a9c08, 0x88e8a9)
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1369 +0x89
runtime.parkunlock(0x8a9c08, 0x88e8a9)
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1385 +0x3b
runfinq()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2644 +0xcf
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445

goroutine 33 [syscall, 7 minutes]:
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445
```

I have tried to recover from this and redo the transformOriginal function with a function called transformOriginalWithRecover. Which implements a defer recover and then calls transformOriginal. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

My recovery function, which calls the function that then calls Leptonica via C is:

```
func (p *pageStruct) transformOriginalWithRecover(savefile string, detectOrientation bool, ontry, maxtries int) error {
    var err error = nil
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            ontry++
            if ontry >= maxtries {
                err = errors.New(`Failed to transform original.`)
            } else {
                if verbose {
                    fmt.Println(`Transform panicked. Recovered and retrying.`)
                }
                p.transformOriginalWithRecover(savefile, detectOrientation, ontry, maxtries)
            }
        }
    }()
    p.transformOriginal(savefile, detectOrientation)
    return err
}
```

Which I call with `p.transformOriginalWithRecover(filename, true, 0, 5)` to indicate it should try to recover 5 times before giving up.

Any idea how I can either solve this or somehow recover from a panic that was instigated from C?

**UPDATE**

Here is the specific function that is causing this problem. The panic happens inside of `C.pixClipRectangle` randomly. It is more likely to happen the longer Leptonica takes to clip the image, which of course makes sense as that gives the GC more time to decide to activate.

```
func (p *goPix) Crop(x, y, w, h int) (*goPix, error) {
    startX, startY, width, height := C.l_int32(x), C.l_int32(y), C.l_int32(w), C.l_int32(h)
    box := C.boxCreateValid(startX, startY, width, height)
    if box == nil {
        box = C.boxCreateValid(startX, startY, width, height)
        if box == nil {
            return p, errors.New(`Unable to create box.`)
        }
    }
    newpix := C.pixClipRectangle(p.cPix, box, nil)
    if newpix != p.cPix {
        p.Free()
    }
    C.boxDestroy(&box)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(box))
    if newpix == nil {
        return nil, errors.New(`Crop failed`)
    }
    pix := &goPix{
        cPix: newpix,
    }
    return pix, nil
}
```

Comment: Have you run the race condition detector on the program?

Comment: No, why would it be a race condition?

Comment: Because you said "sometimes randomly"?

Comment: Right OK. I will look up race condition and implement the detector. Thanks.

Comment: Another possibility is if you're passing a pointer to C that goes out of scope and is occasionaly GC'ed before the cgo call returns.

Comment: That was a very good suggestion, but I've looked at the code and I can't see how that could be happening. But it certainly is something to do with `nil` pointers. But I can't figure out why it's happening sometimes and not other times.

Comment: Can you test with `env GOGC=off ./app`? if it doesn't crash then it's the gc reclaiming memory like @JimB suggested.

Comment: @OneOfOne So it is the GC reclaiming the memory, but... I don't understand why as this there is no reason for it to go out of scope. There are 2 C structs, both stored as pointers in Go variables, in the main body of the function, that are set within the function and destroyed at the end of the function. I have updated the question with this function so you can see.

Comment: I'd have to see the actual function calling the C code.

Comment: Sorry, it's here now. I was updating as you were writing.

Comment: Do you have any form of parallelism in the caller code?

Comment: Nope, this is single threaded. Or at least, I am not creating any additional Goroutines.

Comment: I did a million tests and I've found that it still happens when GC is off and it doesn't happen on blank images. Possibly it is a Leptonica bug?

Comment: Could be. Is there a reason you don't use the native [package](http://blog.golang.org/go-imagedraw-package)?